# Interpreting y axis in density plot

Tags: r, density-function, beta-distribution

200 people were tested, 20 of those were infected. I want to get a posterior distribution for the uncertainty associated with the probability that a person is infected.

I do this like this:

```
n<-200
s<-20
p<-seq(0,0.3,0.001)

dp<-dbeta(p, s+1, n-s+1)
```

But then when I plot it, I don't know how to interpret the y axis and summary results:

```
plot(p, dp, type="l")
```

[image]

```
> summary(dp)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0.000000  0.000011  0.032438  3.322259  3.841204 18.820899
```

So there is a 10% chance of.....something being 18.82? Or? What does this summary tell me?

Also, what is the difference between the first plot and the plot below?

```
plot(density(dp))
```

[image]

Comment: Your second plot is meaningless (at most it tells you most of the density is close to $0$).

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-is-a-density-function). Very briefly, density is a *relative* number (usually chosen so that the full curve integrates to 1). Your second density of a density is pretty meaningless, other than that it shows most of the probability densities for $p$ are close to zero I guess (but it says nothing about for *which values* of $p$ this is which is the relevant part).

Comment: In your first plot of the posterior density, the $y$ axis is telling you the density, which you need to integrate to get a probability. So for example  you might estimate visually  the posterior probability that $x$ is  between $0.09$ and $0.11$ (where the density is around $18$) is going to be roughly about $(0.11-0.99)\times18 = 0.36$ and then check it with `pbeta(0.11,21,181)-pbeta(0.09,21,181)`  giving `0.3628953` or with `sum(dp[p<=0.11&p>0.09])*0.001` giving `0.362944`

Answer (score 2):

> But then when I plot it, I don't know how to interpret the y axis

The first plot is a probability density plot of a beta distribution. The y-axis is the density and you would not normally try to interpret this. It is scaled so that the total area under the curve is 1.

> and summary results:
> `summary(dp)`

> ```
>  Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.
> 0.000000  0.000011  0.032438  3.322259  3.841204 18.820899
> ```

> So there is a 10% chance of.....something being 18.82? Or? What does this summary tell me?`

No, 18.820899 is the maximum value. This summary tells you

1. The minimum and maximum values of the data
2. The interquartile range ( 0.000011, 3.841204)
3. The mean and median

Notice how much larger the mean is than the median, indicating that you have a right-skewed distribution.

> Also, what is the difference between the first plot and the plot below?

The 2nd plot is a density of the density, which does not make a lot of sense and I would not try to interpret it.